# How to fix Object cannot be converted to javafx.scene.Node

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to load my fxml file, which is fine and loaded (I have tried it with my main class).  But, when I tried to set the content in the Controller, an error occurred saying:

> incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to javafx.scene.Node
>   at addNewCategorie.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());

My Controller Class:

```
@FXML
private BorderPane mainBorder;

@FXML
public void handle_the_addition_of_newCategorie(){
    Dialog<ButtonType> addNewCategorie = new Dialog<>();
    addNewCategorie.setTitle("Add Categorie");
    addNewCategorie.initOwner(mainBorder.getScene().getWindow());
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/AddNewCategorie.fxml"));
    try{
        addNewCategorie.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());
    }catch (IOException E){
        System.out.println("IOEXception : "+E.getMessage());
    }
    addNewCategorie.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CLOSE);
    addNewCategorie.show();
}
```

My fxml file:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<BorderPane fx:id="mainBorder" fx:controller="sample.Controller"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" style="-fx-background-color:#485460">
    <center>
        <HBox spacing="20" alignment="CENTER">
            <Button text="Add new Categorie" style="-fx-background-color:#2ecc71; -fx-text-fill:white" onMouseClicked="#handle_the_addition_of_newCategorie"/>
        </HBox>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Please follow [naming conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

had to change this:

```
addNewCategorie.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());
```

to:

```
addNewCategorie.getDialogPane().setContent((Node)fxmlLoader.load());
```

and:

```
fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/AddNewCategorie.fxml"));
```

To:

```
fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/AddNewCategorie.fxml"));
```

Comment: the second change isn't needed (it's the exact same resource location, an absolute path to a resource located in the default package) - so there might be something else weird

Comment: Not only is the second change not needed (as mentioned by @kleopatra), but the first change shouldn't be needed either. By virtue of the `load` method's signature, the return type should have been inferred to be `Node` in the original code (i.e. no need for the explicit cast). What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @Slaw suspected that also, but wasn't entirely certain - thanks for the explanation :) In sum, this answer is simply wrong for the general case ..

Comment: @Slaw i m using 8